# (PHP) How do I return regular MySQL result resources when using prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysqli

This is a bit of a clueless-beginner type of question, so I apologise. But I've not managed to find a website or video that helps me understand working with MySQL prepared statements, so I'm hoping for some direct advice.

For the last couple of weeks of my learning, I've been using procedural MySQLi calls to make database queries, and working through them with while loops. Things like

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `Shoes` WHERE `Color` = 'Red'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['size'];
}
```

Things like that. It makes sense to me that I would be execute a query, get returned a special results resource, and then use a 'fetch_something' function to turn it into an array I can pick from and loop over, regardless of its size.

Now I'm trying to learn about prepared statements. What's tripping me up is the 'bind_result' function that seems to get used all the time, at least in every book and tutorial I've consulted so far. It tells me to provide one variable per column, to which the result for that column will be bound. Like

```
$db = new mysqli(server,user,pass,database);
$stmt = $db->prepare("select `Temperature` from `BuildingDetails` where `HouseNumber` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['num']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($x);
$stmt->fetch();
echo "The temperature in this house is {$x}.";
```

Simple enough when I'm retrieving a single value, or a single row. But what if I want to loop over a table with 20 columns and 5,000 rows? Is there a way I can just return a regular old MySQL result resource and use fetch_assoc or something on it?

Comment: So you have looked at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and found nothing there? Curios, I see _several_ methods there with “fetch” in their name.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can just return a regular old MySQL result resource and use fetch_assoc or something on it?

You can use [mysqli_stmt_get_result](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

**Procedural**

```
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       print_r($row);
    }
```

**OOP**

```
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
      print_r($row);
    }
```

This way you do not have to bind all the variables to get results.

Comment: Thanks for this, that helps a ton Hanky Panky.